# How to return to the previous page, and keep previous page content WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to return to the previous page, and keep previous page content?

I have found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/15c6b838-8402-4fb4-a279-78fafd0e103b/how-to-return-to-the-previous-page-and-keep-previous-page-content?forum=wpf), but there they use a ugly default navigation bar by Microsoft therefore I want to build my own designed nav bar.

How can I do that? I mean I want to navigate from page1 to page2 but when I go back from page2 to page1 I want to return to the same page1 and not to a new instance of it.

Now I'm using this (bad) method:

```
void PreviousButton(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page2 p2 = new Page2();
            NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
        }
```

Comment: when you say "Keep previous page content" you mean to say if there were any data inputted by user, page should retain them ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the ui of a frame then don't use pages and don't use a frame as a host.
I've never seen a commercial team use pages in wpf.

Instead, use a contentcontrol to host your stuff.
Usercontrols instead of Pages.

When you instantiate a new UserControl you can add it to a List and retain a reference to the instance. Keep a current index.  Navigation "back" would use the previous indexed view, forwards the next.

Usually this would be viewmodels rather than any UI object at all and you'd datatemplate each viewmodel into a view ( with the viewmodel as datacontext ).  Retaining a reference to the viewmodel as above.
This viewmodel first navigation is fairly common for child views.
Almost all commercial teams use MVVM.